# select only distinct values - MYSQL 

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a column in my database that is entitled area and when users register they pick an area from 6 options. When I try to setup a search that shows people from those areas using a dropdown menu it duplicates them and only shows one result when the form is submitted.

`SELECT * FROM registration ORDER BY area` is my query and in the dropdown it produces results like:

```
Warwickshire
Warwickshire
Warwickshire
Northamptonshire
```

etc. but I want it to just show Warwickshire once and when you click submit it shows all the people from Warwickshire instead of just the one user.

Any help is appreciated, thanks Richard.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
"SELECT * FROM registration GROUP BY <repeating_column_name> ORDER BY area"
```

Comment: Both this and the DISTINCT methods work great but how can I get it to list the various people that are from that area when the search is completed struggling to get more than one person to show, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT DISTINCT area FROM registration ORDER BY area`

Comment: Thanks works great but how can I get it to list the various people that are from that area when the search is completed struggling to get more than one person to show, thanks

Comment: You're basically going to need to do 2 queries. The above query can be used to populate the list of areas. Once the user selects an area, you can get the users with a query like "SELECT * FROM registration WHERE area = the_area"

Answer (score 1):

use `distinct` clause to get you the uniq data. You can' apply distinct to `*`; specify the particular column you are trying to get. Your case, if it's area then try

```
select distinct area from registration order by area;
```

Comment: Thanks works great but how can I get it to list the various people that are from that area when the search is completed struggling to get more than one person to show, thanks

Comment: Not sure how your tables ae structured. Show, your table(s) structure and will help you to get the info you are looking for.

I mean, are the relations between people and area present in different table and how they are related?

Comment: Basically users register http://newmedia.leeds.ac.uk/ug10/cs10rm/Rating/FINAL/register.php here and they select an area of play.

The table structure is as follows ID, username, password, teamname, area, imagelocation, user_likes and datelog.

I want to show it so when a user searches here http://newmedia.leeds.ac.uk/ug10/cs10rm/Rating/FINAL/search.php it shows all the users who have the same area as a list showing their username, teamname, user_likes and possibly the image (which I can sort).